# How to move Layer to the back?

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

from my Plugin I've loaded a rasterlayer using the following code:

```
fileName = "/path/to/raster/file.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
if rlayer.isValid():
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
    ...
```

Now I wonder how I can move the freshly loaded layer to the back, that it lies behind all previously loaded layers.

Answer (score 2):

i have not come across to change layer order for taking an instance to back of all layers. But i think you can use **addTopLevelItems(items)** function for getting all layers to top without your current layer. Maybe it is a reverse solution but i hope it works for your needs.

```
PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidget.addTopLevelItems(items)

Parameters: items – PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem
Appends the items  as a top-level item in the widget.
```

Selecting current layer,

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
cLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
```

Or all layers,

```
allLayers = canvas.layers()
for i in allLayers: print i
```

i hope it helps you....